# AJAX chat without periodic refresh?

Tags: php, html, ajax, chat

I'm about to write a ajax based Chat. 
What is the best way to refresh the chat box? I know there are few possibilitys but which is best suited for a Chat?

Additional:
Is it possible just to reload the unread text? If someone writes an text it isn't nessecarry to refresh the whole content.The new message would be enough. But can it be done with ajax and php? I have no idea how it could be done. So I would be thankfull for even a tipp ...
Thanks!

Comment: There are techniques like web sockets that allow you to avoid polling, but they're pretty complicated and probably not worth the development overhead.

And sure -- just send a timestamp with each poll corresponding to the timestamp of the last poll. The server can respond only with messages newer than the included timestamp.

Comment: This question is fairly broad. I suggest researching AJAX and then narrowing down your question. Also, it couldn't hurt to look for a pre-made chat module you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency of the refresh and the scope of content to be refresh are independent. With AJAX, you can ask the server if any new message arrived (based on timestamp), and append only those to the already displayed content, you don't have to reload the whole page.

As for the 'periodic refresh' thing: you can go either for short polling or long polling. I think by 'periodic refresh' you may refer to short polling. This is basically a timer, e.g. in every second the server is polled by the JavaScript is there is any new data to be displayed. If yes, it sends it, otherwise replies with a message indicating there is no new content.

Whilst in long polling, the server is polled, and gives the new content if it has it. However, if there is no new content, then instead of giving immediate answer of 'no new content', but keeps the connection open, and answers when it has something to send. This can be achieved in several different ways, and theoretically provides better response time, but in practice, it can result in timeout, or heavy reasource usage on the server, if it is implemented in a certain way.

You can see a long polling example here: http://www.screenr.com/SNH